# Tablesorter hide filters of hidden columns

Tags: php, jquery, css, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the tablesorter plugin in my html table.

The issue is that I have some "display:none" columns that only are shown if I click a toggle button (my table is very long and I need this functionality).

The problem is that Tablesorter don't hide the filters of the hidden columns.

[image]

What I need is to display:none the filters that its TH is already display:none.

Thank you and ask me if you need further details.

Comment: See this git forum post: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/477. It may be helpful for you in your quest.

Comment: I have seen this post but I dont know how to implement it.

Where and what I need to change?
I have coded this script that works but I don't know if is good:

var myfilters = new Array(6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65);
for (i = 0; i <= myfilters.length; i++) {
$("td[data-column='"+(myfilters[i]-1)+"']").css("display","none");    
}

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods to hide the filter cells:

- Whatever class you are adding to hide the column, include it in the [`filter_cellFilter` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-cellfilter) in an array.

  ```
  // hiding second & fourth columns using associated css
  filter_cssFilter : [ '', 'hidden', '', 'hidden' ]
  ```
- Use the following css to hide the entire column instead of adding a class to each cell within the column

  ```
  #mytable th:nth-child(10), #mytable td:nth-child(10),
  #mytable th:nth-child(11), #mytable td:nth-child(11),
  #mytable th:nth-child(12), #mytable td:nth-child(12) /* etc */ {
    display: none;
  }
  ```

I am also curious as to why you would need so many hidden columns. It is also possible to add the extra values in data-attributes, then with some special parsing you can sort or filter using that extra data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I hide some columns in order to have a simple view of the table with the main values and when I press a button I display the full table with the scroll bars. The problem was that the pluggin do not hide the filters of the hidden columns by default.

Comment: The code snipped shown uses cssFilter, which didn't work for me, but the link is for cellFilter, which did.